# How to start VirtualBox using commandline?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, virtualbox

I've VirtualBox on a Windows 7 PC and created a virtual machine for Windows XP. Here is what I want to do:

1. Run VirtualBox
2. Power on guest OS (named "Windows XP")
3. Open Winword in guest OS

I want to accomplish these 3 steps at once (by using a batch file for example).

Any help would be appreciated.

In fact I've a batch file but it does not work as I wanted:

```
"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\Vboxmanage.exe" startvm "Windows XP"
TIMEOUT 30
"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxmanage.exe" guestcontrol "Windows XP" execute --image "C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~2\OFFICE11\WINWORD.EXE" --username xpuser
```

Comment: What happens when you run your bat file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your script, I assume that your Windows XP user has no password (you only include the username flag)

The command that VBoxManage sends is done using a Windows remote session and by default, blank passwords are not allowed.

Do this in your Windows XP VM:

1. Start -> Run -> Regedit
2. Browse to `[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa]`
3. Change the value of `LimitBlankPasswordUse` to `0`

Your script should now work as expected

Also, if your VM is closed in a saved state, you shouldn't need to include the `TIMEOUT` command as `Vboxmanage.exe startvm` should wait for the VM to load before exiting.

If you shut down the VM when finished with it then the `TIMEOUT` should probably stay.

Comment: @@Shevek, thanks for the quick response. Actually I've added winword.exe to the startup group in VM and works fine. However, I was trying to do this using a batch file so that I can create batch files for any program I want. I've edited my first post and included the batch file I'm trying to make it work.

Comment: @MuratArpat - I have edited, with a different answer, hopefully the solution

Comment: @ Shevek - I got it worked with your regedit solution, only after adding TIMEOUT line again. I do not know why but guest OS desktop should be loaded otherwise the line after TIMEOUT line does not work, and value added with TIMEOUT is also important. For example, TIMEOUT 10 does not work while TIMEOUT 15 and above works.

Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Ah, I think it may be because my VM was in a saved state so the launch was almost immediate.

Comment: I've edited the answer

Comment: I've just tried, and you are right. If VM was in a saved state TIMEOUT line in the batch file is not necessary. And, the reason I did not use SLEEP command is that I did not want the person who will use this batch file bother with keypress.

Comment: I've removed the SLEEP bit from my answer.